# Select rows i and i+1 from data frame

Tags: r, loops

I have several log files, which I read into one long data.frame (log file 1 followed by log file 2 etc.). Demonstration of what the variable looks like:

```
Event.Type
Picture 
Response 
Picture
Response 
Response 
Response 
Picture
Response
Response
```

In other words, the pattern is one `Picture` to one or more `Response`s. My current objective is to extract each Picture followed by the *first* Response, i.e.:

```
Picture
Response
Picture
Response
...
```

My most successful attempt so far was to extract all pictures:

```
picrows <- which(bps$Event.Type=="Picture")
output <- bps[picrows,]
write.table(output, file='bps.tab')
```

after which I attempted with a loop to add the row following each picture row, which didn't seem to work:

```
i=1
for (i in 1:length(bps)) 
  { 
  picrows[i] <- which(bps$Event.Type=="Picture")
  output <- rbind(bps[picrows[i],], bps[picrows[i+1],])
  write.table(output, file='bps.tab')
  i = i+1
  }
output
```

This took the first Picture row and added a seemingly random other picture row to the table, i.e. two rows altogether. Where has my thinking gone wrong? Except that loops are apparently not the most elegant way to proceed on R.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this (without the need for loops):

```
# get indices of pictures:
i <- which(d$Event.Type == "Picture")
# subset rows in i and i+1:
d[sort(c(i, i+1)),, drop =FALSE]
#  Event.Type
#1    Picture
#2   Response
#3    Picture
#4   Response
#7    Picture
#8   Response
```

You can check what's happening when you run these lines step by step:

```
i
#[1] 1 3 7
i+1
#[1] 2 4 8
c(i, i+1)
#[1] 1 3 7 2 4 8
sort(c(i, i+1))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 7 8
```

---

Sample data in reproducible form:

```
d <- structure(list(Event.Type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Picture", "Response"), class = "factor")), .Names = "Event.Type", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

---

I will use `d2` as a second example data set where one of the "Picture"s is not directly followed by a "Response":

```
d2 <- d[-2, , drop=FALSE]
```

**a)** If you are not sure whether each "Picture" is followed by at least 1 "Response", you can do the following to avoid returning some pictures multiple times (but return all pictures regardless whether they are followed by "Response"):

```
i <- which(d2$Event.Type == "Picture")
ii <- c(i, intersect(i+1, which(d2$Event.Type == "Response")))
d2[sort(ii),, drop =FALSE]
#  Event.Type
#1    Picture
#3    Picture
#4   Response
#7    Picture
#8   Response
```

**b)** If you only want to return those rows of "Picture" which are followed by at least 1 "Response", you can use the following modification:

```
i <- which(d2$Event.Type == "Picture")
ii <- c(i, i+1)[d2$Event.Type[i+1] == "Response"]
d2[sort(ii),, drop =FALSE]
#  Event.Type
#3    Picture
#4   Response
#7    Picture
#8   Response
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked like a charm! I have a further (related) question and hope that it's OK to post that as a comment here. Some Picture rows didn't have corresponding Responses; with this programming it comes up as three Consecutive picture rows in output (e.g. Picture 1 (i), Picture 2 afterwards (i+1), and Picture 2 again (new i)). Any ideas on how I can avoid this?

Many thanks again for your very thorough answer!

Comment: Wonderful, thanks a lot!! If you're ever in Berlin, a jar of homemade chutney has got your name on it!

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts come to mind for me:

- rbind: if you want to keep appending the rows to the output var, include it as the first parameter.

  `output <- rbind(output, bps[picrows[i],], bps[picrows[i+1],])`
- picrows will only have Picture row indexes. Maybe you want to + 1 to the original picrows[i] as in the following, rather than [i+1]:

  `output <- rbind(output, bps[picrows[i],], bps[picrows[i]+1,])`

Good luck!